# Logrotate: run every N hours

Tags: logrotate

Consider a server which generates extensive logging, which are archived using [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) and bz2:

```
"/var/log/uwsgi/*/*.log" {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 14
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
  compresscmd /bin/bzip2
  uncompresscmd /bin/bunzip2
  compressext .bz2
}
```

Using `hourly` rotation is not convenient for log inspection in real time (problems tend to happen just when the hour changes), and `daily` rotation gets the disk full far to often.

Is there a way to set logrotate to run every given amount of hours? An invocation every 6 hours would be perfect for my case.

Answer (score 6):

Running the `logrotate` commad with `-f` in a cronjob could be enough. From [`man logrotate`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/logrotate):

```
-f, --force
      Tells logrotate to force the rotation, even if it doesn't  think
      this  is  necessary.   Sometimes this is useful after adding new
      entries to a logrotate config file, or if  old  log  files  have
      been  removed  by  hand,  as  the new files will be created, and
      logging will continue correctly.
```

So edit `/etc/crontab` and add:

```
30 */6 * * * root logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```

Change the minute to suit your needs. The `*/6` means it should run every six hours.

---

This will rotate all *log* files, so isolate the settings for the application to a (self-contained) config file, then use that as the parameter. For example, create `/etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi`, containing:

```
"/var/log/uwsgi/*/*.log" {
  copytruncate
  daily
  rotate 14
  compress
  delaycompress
  missingok
  notifempty
  compresscmd /bin/bzip2
  uncompresscmd /bin/bunzip2
  compressext .bz2
}
```

along with any other lines in `/etc/logrotate.conf` that you may be implicitly relying on. Then the `crontab` entry will look like:

```
30 */6 * * * root logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/uwsgi
```

Comment: +1, But that would cause every log in the system (not just `/var/log/uwsgi/*/*.log`) to be rotated every 6 hours.

Comment: @AdamMatan If you can isolate the settings for that particular set of logs into a config file, you can pass that config file as an argument to `logrotate`.